# Omniture Site Catalyst Extract/Export/Download Report Data

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have a drilled down report as shown in the below image:

[image]

When I try to download the report normally, I get only the 5 items shown in a category. I want to be able to download all the subcategories within all the categories, along with the category names and not just the 5 subcategories in a category.

How can I achieve this? Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: Do you have access to data warehouse?

Comment: I don't believe we do. This was a third party application built for a client. How can I utilize the data warehouse feature if i can somehow get access?

Comment: The data warehouse will allow you to pull that data in its entirety. It would formatted in columns like this: Series Name | Video Name | Metric1 etc. I don't know if there is a way to pull that from the reporting UI without doing one series at a time.

Comment: Great! Thank you BrettAHale. I'll try to see if I can get access as that would make life easier!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to data warehouse, you can obtain this information easily. Most contracts include it by default; if you have access to the request interface, you have it.

1. Click on Adobe Marketing Cloud in the upper left | Reports & Analytics | Data Warehouse
2. Select the date range you'd like to request data from
3. In the breakdowns section, select series name following by video name
4. In the metrics section, select the appropriate metric you'd like to include
5. Ensure the other settings in the request are as desired, and click 'request report'.

If you don't have access to data warehouse, you could try your luck at a data extract report:

1. Open the report you'd like to download, and under more options there should be 'extract data'
2. In the data extract wizard, click each 'top 1-50' and set them to 'all' or 'top 1-50000'
3. Ensure the other settings in the request are as desired, and click 'request report'.

Data extracts are subject to processing limitations, meaning if there's too much data to process, the request will fail. Data warehouse on the other hand is not subject to this limitation, it just takes a really long time for the report to arrive.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option would be to write your own script to pull the data using Adobe's [Analytics Reporting API](https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/documentation/sitecatalyst-reporting/c-reporting-api)

Also a note about Data Warehouse.. it's "free" for anybody on a newer Adobe Digital Marketing contract.  I say "free" because it's now included in the "package" with most all of the other adobe digital marking tools, instead of being charged separately.

If you have an older contract that hasn't been renewed yet, you may not actually have it, since part of it now being included also involves them jacking up the prices! Contact your rep to find out. But if you do have access to Data Warehouse, that's certainly the easier route.